# Echoing out most recent database records?

Tags: php

I have a section of my website that reads out data to the user.

My current code reads out data in the same order, even when new records are added; they are added at the end of the data that is being echoed out.
I want to read out the most recent data as I am creating a message board.

**CODE:**

```
session_start();
$sess = $_GET['id'];
$profile_query = "SELECT * from forum WHERE postee = $sess";
$profile_queried = mysql_query($profile_query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($profile_queried))
{
    echo '<div class="each_post"><p>'.$row['content'].'</p></div>';
}
```

**Question:** How can I echo data from a database in order of recency? Must I add another field to do this?

Comment: You should use date field to achieve this task

Comment: This is very unsafe code.  Someone could easily trash your server.  You may want to browse over this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839523/secure-against-sql-injection-pdo-mysqli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
$profile_query = "SELECT * from forum WHERE postee = $sess ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Comment: Hmm getting a boolean error when I add this. **mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**

Comment: @RobertTossly there must be some `column` that should have `increment value`, be sure you're using that name in query instead of `id`

Comment: @RobertTossly try like this `$profile_query = "SELECT * from forum WHERE postee = '$sess' ORDER BY postee DESC"`

Comment: @RobertTossly Change your code to this: `mysql_fetch_array($profile_queried, MYSQL_ASSOC)`

Comment: I prefer that it must be date to be desc. @RobertTossly Can i know the column name of your date?

Comment: `if( ! $profile_queried )` then your query failed and you don't have a valid resource to pass to mysql_fetch_array(), you can discover exactly why with mysql_error http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php, also, note that mysql is deprecated, mysqli or PDO is recommended.

Comment: Ahhh I've added an id auto-incrementing column. Then I have added ORDER BY id DESC. Thanks for showing me my problem.